# AngularJS Adding row to a ng-repeat model - How to focus on the newly added row 1st input?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, autofocus

I am trying to add autofocus to the first element in ng-repeat

```
<div class="border-row" {{$first?focus-autofocus:''}} ng-repeat="item in itemsList" >
```

But this doesn't work. I'm using https://github.com/obogo/angular-focusmanager. How can I go about adding this?

Comment: How would you like to show your itemsList???? like in <li> or lable or textbox

Comment: itemsList has divs that contains text and some conditional buttons

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list in your itemList, then

```
<div class="border-row" ng-repeat="item in itemsList" >

<input ng-model="item.id" type="text" custom-autofocus="$index == 0" >
```

Create a directive for this:

```
    .directive('customAutofocus', function() {
  return{
         restrict: 'A',

         link: function(scope, element, attrs){
           scope.$watch(function(){
             return scope.$eval(attrs.customAutofocus);
             },function (newValue){
               if (newValue == true){
                   element[0].focus();
               }
           });
         }
     };
})
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of the $index property.$index is 0 for first element.
One of the solution may be :

```
<div class="border-row" ng-repeat="item in itemsList" >
<div ng-if="$index==0" focus-autofocus>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Adding another div for just one attribute would not be the cleanest solution

Answer (score 0):

Interpolation doesn't works anywhere inside a tag. It must be the value of an attribute.

I'm not aware of that library but shouldn't this work?

```
<div class="border-row" focus-autofocus ng-repeat="item in itemsList" >
```

Or:

```
<div class="border-row" focus-autofocus ng-repeat="item in itemsList track by $index" >
```

Comment: The first one would add focus-autofocus to all elements in the ng-repeat. But I want it added only to the first one

Comment: Try `focus-autofocus="{{$index}}"`

Comment: Is adds focus-autofocus to all new rows with consecutive indexes